# Quarter over Quarter do not list in sequence 1,2,3,4

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

### Would you know why Power BI will not list years with Quarters in sequence?

I uploaded my aggregated data into Matrix visual. All data listed, however, 
Quarter column begins with Q2, Q1, Q4, Q3. I switch over into DATA, and quarters list in sequence. I am currently using the following year over year, 2015,2016,2017,2018,2019. Also, I have on another column "Days Outstanding" 90/120/180/365.

```
Quarter
_________
QTR2
QTR1
QTR4
QTR3
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Power BI is sorting by another field like Month[name], etc

- One trick to get Power BI to sort the right way is to add a numeric column in the source or calendar table which you can use in your grid to sort by. 
  This numeric column can be hidden or collapsed, so users cannot see it.
- Grids provide three dots menu to allow you to sort by a different column (ascending or descending)
- Tip #2 is to use the "Sort by Column" option under the Modeling menu.